# How can I interpret dates returned from ggvis handle_click

Tags: r, date, ggvis

First experience of using handle_click

```
library(ggvis)
library(dplyr)

# create data.frame
counts <- c(1,2)
dates <- as.Date(c("2015-01-01","2015-01-02"))
df <- data.frame(count=counts,date=dates)


# function to view clicked data
getDate = function(data,location,session){
  if(is.null(data)) return(NULL)
  glimpse(data)
}

df %>% 
  ggvis(~date,~count) %>% 
  layer_points() %>% 
  handle_click(getDate)
```

This returns when clicking  the first point

```
Observations: 1
Variables:
$ date  (dbl) 1.42007e+12
$ count (int) 1
```

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dates appear as milliseconds from the origin time which is considered to be `1970-01-01 00:00:00`.

As you can see you can transform that back to your original date using:

```
> as.POSIXct(1.42007e+12/1000, origin='1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT')
[1] "2014-12-31 23:53:20 GMT"
```

The error of 6minutes is due to a rounding error I suppose.

You could change your script to see the dates as they should appear like this:

```
# function to view clicked data
getDate = function(data,location,session){
  if(is.null(data)) return(NULL)
  #just added the below line in your code
  data$date <- as.Date(as.POSIXct((data$date)/1000, origin='1970-01-01 00:10:00 GMT'))
  glimpse(data)
}

df %>% 
  ggvis(~date,~count) %>% 
  layer_points() %>% 
  handle_click(getDate)
```

Which returns on click:

```
Observations: 1
Variables:
$ date  (date) 2015-01-01
$ count (dbl) 1
```

Comment: / Thanks for that. Do you think we should have to do that transformation or should I report it as a bug?

Comment: You are welcome! Happy to have helped :). I don't think it is a bug to be honest because there is a way to overcome it. It can be an enhancement though for sure, so if you want to report it as such it is up to you :)

Comment: One more piece of assistance, if possible, In a Shiny app how would I reference this date in a reactive?

Comment: Hi. I don't know exactly what the problem is or if I get the question correctly but if you mean access the vector from a reactive function just load the `df` from a `global.r` script using the `readRDS` function (obviously after you have saved it as .RDS) and then you can use the date anywhere using the above code. I suggest if this is not what you are asking, to ask a new question explaining what the problem is, providing sample data. Please add the link here too so that I can take a look too.

Comment: Tx Here it is  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30536486/how-do-i-reference-a-clicked-point-on-a-ggvis-plot-in-shiny